# How do you inject a derived class as a service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, derived-class

I want to separate the interface of a service used by my components from its implementation (to simplify creation of capable hand crafted mocks, it so happens), and have the implementation injected as a dependency for the components that use it. This approach is common-place for Java Spring back-ends.

So, if I have code like this:

```
export abstract class AbstractMyService {// Defines the interface of the service
   ...
}

export class MyService extends AbstractMyService {// The concrete implementation
   ...
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-myComponent',
    templateUrl: './my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private readonly service: AbstractMyService) {
    }

    ...
}
```

How do I ensure that when `MyComponent` is instanced in the application it has an object of the `MyService` type passed to its constructor?

I know that if I was *not* separating the interface and implementation (so `MyService` was a concrete class and `AbstractMyService` did not exist), I could simply do it thus:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
   ...
}
```

Do I simply need to annotate `MyService` as `@Injectable`? Or must I do something more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare an implementation as a *provider* explicitly

```
@NgModule({ // or @Component, depending on the place you want to configure.
....
  providers: [{ 
    provide: AbstractMyService,
    useClass: MyService
  }]
})
```

there is no way to "autodetect" in the way it is done in Spring. That piece of configuration explicitly says that if something injects item using token `AbstractMyService`, class `MyService` would be used as a constructor.

In the common case that you want all components to use the same concrete class, you would declare that *provider* for your `AppModule`. For unit tests, you would declare the provider as part of your `TestBed` configuration:

```
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         declarations: [MyComponent],
         providers: [
            ...
            { provide: AbstractMyService, useFactory: () => { return new MockMyService(...); } }]
        });
```